# Prove for any integer $a$, one of the integers $a$, $a+2$, $a+4$ is divisible by $3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove for any integer $a$, one of the integers $a$, $a+2$, $a+4$ is divisible by $3$.

I know I would use the division algorithm but I am really confused how to go about this. Step by step explanation please? thank you so much!

Comment: Each number leaves a remainder of either $0$, $1$, or $2$ when divisible by $3$, according to the division algorithm. Convince yourself that no two of them are the same, and think about Pigeonhole.

Answer (score 1):

For every number **$a$**: $a \equiv {0, 1, 2} \pmod{3}$

In the first case: $a \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$

For the second one:
$a \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ =>
$a+2 \equiv 3 \pmod{3} \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$

For the third one:
$a \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$ =>
$a+4 \equiv 6 \pmod{3} \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\, 3\mid a\!\iff\! 3\mid a\!+\!3.\ $  $\ a\!+\!2,a\!+\!3,a\!+\!4\,$ are $3$ consecutive integers, [so](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/860502/242) $3$ divides one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try working modulo 3:

So we have:

$$a \equiv a \pmod 3$$
$$a + 2 \equiv a-1 \pmod 3$$
$$a + 4 \equiv a+1 \pmod 3$$

So those three numbers have same remainder when divided by 3 as $a, a+1, a-1$ and we know that exactly one of 3 consecutive number is divisible by 3.

Answer (score 0):

$a$ is either odd or even. Write $a=2k$ in the first case. Then we are looking at $\{2k, 2(k+1), 2(k+2)\}$. And we know that any three consecutive integers has an integer divisible by three, thus so do this set.

In the second case write $a=2k+1$. Then we are looking at $\{2k+1, 2k+3, 2k+5\}$. This is the same as $\{2(k-1)+3, 2k+3$, and $2(k+1)+3\}$. Likewise one of $\{k-1, k, k+1\}$ is divisible by three. Thus when you multiply by two and add 3 to that one element you still have something divisible by three.

Answer (score 0):

You really only have to check the three possible cases for $a$. (Normally I wouldn't suggest this "proof by exhaustion", but this problem is simple enough.)

**Case I: $\displaystyle a \equiv 0 (\mod 3)$**

$a$ is divisible by $3$, problem solved.

**Case II: $\displaystyle a \equiv 1 (\mod 3)$**

$\displaystyle a+2 \equiv 1+2 \equiv 3 \equiv 0 (\mod 3)$, and $a+2$ is divisible by $3$.

**Case III: $\displaystyle a \equiv 2 (\mod 3)$**

$\displaystyle a+4 \equiv 2+4 \equiv 6 \equiv 0 (\mod 3)$, and $a+4$ is divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
a + x = 3p + \delta\,,\quad x = 0, 2, 4\,,\quad p,\delta \in {\mathbb Z}\,,\quad
\delta = 0,1,2
$$

> $$
> \begin{array}{}
> \delta = 0 & \imp & x = 0\,, & 3 | a 
> \\
> \delta = 1 & \imp & x = 4\,, & 3 | \pars{a + 4} 
> \\
> \delta = 2 & \imp & x = 2\,, & 3 | \pars{a + 2}
> \end{array}
> $$