# Prove $a, a + 2$, or $a + 4$ is composite?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I've been assigned a proof by contrapositive for:

> If $a$ is a natural number and $a, a + 2$, and $a + 4$ are
>   prime, then $a = 3$.

So, the contrapositive I've produced is as follows:

> If $a \neq 3$, then it is not true that $a, a + 2$, and $a + 4$ are prime.

How would I go about proving this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint: Write $a= 3k + r$ where $r$ is the remainder of $a$ when divided by 3.

Comment: This problem has been already posted in MSE. In  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2055623/show-that-there-are-no-prime-triplet-other-than-3-5-7 where already was duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's do it looking at residue of $a$ modulo $3$:

If $a=3k$, for some $k>1$, then $a$ is not prime. Thus suppose $a\ne 3k$.

Now if $a=3k+1$, then $a+2=3k+1+2=3(k+1)$ is not prime.

If $a=3k+2$, then $a+2=3(k+1)+1$ and $a+4=3k+6=3(k+2)$ and $a+4$ is not prime.

Therefore, the only posibility for $a$ is $a=3$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Edited. Thenks

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use induction to prove that $a$, $a + 2$, or $a + 4$ is a multiple of $3$:

If $f(a)=a(a+2)(a+4)$, then $f(a+1)-f(a)=3 (a^2 + 5 a + 5)$.