# Show that there are not infinitely many triples $\{n, n+2,n+4\},$ all of whose entries are prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Should this be proof by contradiction? Any hint and help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that we cannot have a prime triplet of the form $p$, $p + 2$, $p + 4$ for $p &gt;3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653536/show-that-we-cannot-have-a-prime-triplet-of-the-form-p-p-2-p-4-for)

Answer (score 5):

Hint: exactly one of $n,n+2,n+4$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: So let says if  n, n+2 and n+4 are all divisible by 3, then there are infinitely many triples?

Comment: No, the point is that if a triple $\{n,n+2,n+4\}$ consists of three primes, then since one of the three is divisible by $3$ it must actually be equal to $3$. This limits the number of possible triples.

Comment: Ok, Thanks alot.